# Is there a way to figure out whether the image is rendered or not in overleaf?

Tags: graphics, overleaf

I have a project in Overleaf with a plenty of images, which are not included in the document and I would like to find and remove all the images, which are not included in the `.tex` file. Is there a functionality in Overleaf allowing to do this, or one has to do this by hand?

Comment: the log file will show every image included (if you are using the standard latex packages) so just compare that with your project file list

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, however, it doesn't simplify the problem a lot. One needs still to remove them one by one

Comment: or delete them all (which you can probably do in less clicks) then re-upload all the used ones from a local copy of the project with a cleaned up file list.

Comment: You can also use \fbox to see how much white space is generated.